# HTML/Javascript get variable on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In some website pages, when i try to open the "View Source" with google chrome, and check the hidden values, I find out that the `val` is blank, but when i inspect the form, i can actually see the content of that hidden value,

for example, [this site](https://www.clixsense.com/en/Sign_In), when i try check the source i can't see the `nid` value, 
I think it has something to do with this function,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function upuid(a){
        $('input[name="nid"]').val(a)
    }
</script>
```

but I can't find where it is being called and what is the `a` parameter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The view page source page shows you the exact text that was returned by the server. Inspect element actually shows you the fully rendered DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

The value is set from the client side. That's why you can't see it in the source. My guess the method get's called from the https://www.clixsense.com/uid.swf through ExternalInterface.call. The "a" is a string, and in this case it's a unique identifier.